# My edit gets rejected, when I go back to that question, it appears that is my whole edit there

Tags: discussion

So, I revieved this question. Added code. -> [Mac OS X finder requiring permissions when deleting file, even after chmod](https://superuser.com/questions/778642/mac-os-x-finder-requiring-permissions-when-deleting-file-even-after-chmod)

[image]

My edit gets rejected by a user that has higher reputation than me, and he rejected the edit and edited the question. Then another user gets there and edits question so it now looks like my edit.

So, where is my mistake here? Do I stink or what?

Comment: It happens sometimes, there are other ways to deal with minor edits. I make minor edits on other sites where I only have my Association Bonus (so, 101 rep total), and half the time, edits get rejected. In the grand scheme of things, it doesn't mean much. Keep making edits that you feel help the post, and ignore if people accept them or not. We can't control how other editors think.

Comment: The other user, added additional formatting, you didn't include.  Are you upset your edit was denied or something?  What exactly is your question, the edit approval process worked, your suggested edit was edited + improved

Answer (score 4):

It's one of those things. Typically, when you're a newer user, it's a good idea to have more substantial edits. Stuff like minor formatting edits are often rejected, especially when it's something not everyone agrees with. I'd personally have rejected those edits outright.

When you're higher reputation, there's no actual reputation benefit to edits - so we have more leeway. I've occasionally done one or two character edits because the spelling error *annoyed me*.

At this point, my suggestion would be to do edits other than 'formatting' or simple tag addition for now.

Comment: I'm not a "new" user. This is just stupid.

Comment: @JosipIvic, there are hundreds of edits every day.  This kind of situation happens occasionally just as random chance because no system is bullet-proof ([infinite monkeys theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)).  This time it happened to one of your own edits, so you're keenly aware of it, but in the scheme of things it's unusual.

Comment: @JosipIvic You have less then 500 reputation which means you have not made 250 edits, each worth 2 points, which you basically a new user.

Comment: @JosipIvic the key point here that somebody else need to approve your edit, many of us (including me) don't want to approve small edits like fixing some typos, correcting case of "i"... It's just waste of time.  Later, with enough reputation - when you won't take others' time you will be welcome to do it. Again is not about seniority or experience on the site,just don't waste others' time with something not really important.

Answer (score 1):

Edits have to be constructive, If you just add formatting and nothing else which is useful, your edit is likely to be rejected.

However, if someone has the privilege to edit without it needing review, they might occasionally edit questions with poor formatting...

Comment: look at revisions on question and tell me if my edit is different than rest of edits

Comment: The OP probably thought that even though your edit was rejected, the edit made sense. He/She is free to edit their own question without being reviewed

Comment: It was rejected by another user.

Comment: @JosipIvic Yes. Because It wasn't constructive.

Comment: And his edit is more constructive? Look closely.

Comment: @JosipIvic I asked JourneymanGeek to post something. He's a moderator on the site. Look at his answer...